# way of returning sqlalchemy engine object from init using dictionary switch

Tags: python, switch-statement

Was just creating a helper class for instantiating Sqlalchemy Engine object based on the Vendor used by User.

Is there a way I can return the engine object when the object of my helper class is ceated.

```
class SqlalchemyEngineInitializer:
    def __init__(self,vendor):
        self.vendor = vendor
        self.engine_pool = {
                                        "sqlite": self.sqlite_engine_init,
                                        "postgres": self.postgres_engine_init,
                                        "mysql": self.mysql_engine_init,
                                        "oracle": self.oracle_engine_init}

        self.engine_pool.get(vendor) #how can this be returned

    def postgres_engine_init(self,user:str,password:str,database:str,hostname:str='localhost'):
        "RETURNS POSTGRES SQLALCHEMY ENGINE OBJECT "
        return create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}')

    def sqlite_engine_init(self,user:str,password:str,database:str,hostname:str='localhost'):
        "RETURNS SQLITE SQLALCHEMY ENGINE OBJECT "
        return create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}')
```

From **init** it is not allowing to return
was trying with **new** but without creating instance is it possible and good practice to return from it.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init() method can only return an instance of the class. You could add a property that returns the engine after placing it in a class member.

If you want to simulate a switch statement, you can write a helper function:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

and use it with a for loop:

```
class SqlalchemyEngineInitializer:
    def __init__(self,vendor):
        self.vendor  = vendor
        self._engine = None

    @property
    def engine(self):
        if self._engine: return self._engine
        for case in switch(self.vendor):
            if case("sqlite"):
               self._engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}')
               break
            if case("postgres"):
               self._engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}')
               break
            if case("mysql"):
               ...
               break
            if case("oracle"):
               ...
               break
        return self._engine
```

usage:

```
dbEngine = SqlalchemyEngineInitializer('mysql').engine
```

or

```
db = SqlalchemyEngineInitializer('mysql')

...

... db.engine ...
```

If creating the engine is the only thing your helper class does, then you should make that a function instead:

```
def SqlalchemyEngineInitializer(vendor):
    for case in switch(vendor):
       if case("sqlite"):
           return create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}')
       if case("postgres"):
           return create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}')
       if case("mysql"):
           return ...
       if case("oracle"):
           return ...
```

usage:

```
dbEngine = SqlalchemyEngineInitializer('mysql')
```